# Why won't disconnect work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm writing an application which is based on Apple's Temperature Sensor Application for iOS devices. I'm trying to implement a Disconnect button which will disconnect the currently connected device from the iPhone, however when the disconnect button is pressed there is a `BAD_ACCESS error`, I know this is memory based but I'm completely at a loss on how to fix it. Code follows.

```
- (IBAction)clickbutton:(id)sender 
{

    [[LEConnect sharedInstance] startScan:AccelerometerServiceUUID];
}

- (IBAction)disconnectButton:(id)sender 
{
    CBPeripheral    *peripheral;
    if(CBPeripheralStateDisconnected)
    {
        [[LEConnect sharedInstance] disconnectPeripheral:peripheral];
    }
}
```

The `startScan button` works correctly but the `disconnect button` does not. The code in the button is based on the code for finding devices shown below:

```
if (CBPeripheralStateConnected)
{
    [[LEConnect sharedInstance] connectPeripheral:peripheral];
    [currentlyConnectedDevice setText:[peripheral name]];
}
```

earlier in this function the same `CBPeripheral     *peripheral;` pointer is made.

Sorry if this is a dumb question or has been asked before, I'm just really struggling and in desperate need of help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disconnectButton` method has two errors.  First the `peripheral` variable is used without being initialized (are you ignoring compiler warnings?).  Second, the `if` statement checks if the peripheral is disconnected and then disconnects it again (you should be checking that the peripheral is *connected*).